# Element not covering all height

Tags: html, css

I am having a bug on setting the background color ...

I have a website whose structure is something like this:

```
<body>
<div id="container">
my stuff
```

In the CSS file, I want to set a background image for the body, and a background color for the container. But the background color of the container does not cover all height. Please see what I mean in the website example I refer to below.

```
body {
background-image:url('foto.jpg');
background-color:#000000;
background-size:100%;
background-attachment:fixed;
overflow-y:scroll;
}
#container {
width:760px;
margin:20px auto 0 auto;
color:rgb(230,230,230);
border-width:1px;
border-color:white;
border-style:none solid none solid;
background-color:red;
}
```

The background color of the #container does not expand to the full height of the page.

http://web.fc.up.pt/DGSIII/bug_height/

Comment: try to set height:100% for #container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove `height: 100%;` from `#container`. Divs automatically adapt their height to fit their content.

Is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/t7wsX/

Comment: Thank you, but it did not work out. I applied your suggestion: http://web.fc.up.pt/DGSIII/bug_height/

Comment: I'm sorry, I've read your question more in detail now. Try to look at the updates

Comment: hi, I found the problem. I had something like <div id="container"><div id="header">... and for whatever reason the margin I had for #header was being used as the margin for #content as well. Using padding for the #header did the trick :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this in the body tag

```
body{padding-bottom:0;margin-bottom:0;}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it did not work out. I applied your suggestion: http://web.fc.up.pt/DGSIII/bug_height/

Answer (score 0):

Try below `CSS`

```
#container {
    width:760px;
    margin:20px auto 0 auto;
    color:rgb(230,230,230);
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:white;
    border-style:none solid none solid;
    background-color:red;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it did not work out. I applied your suggestion: http://web.fc.up.pt/DGSIII/bug_height/

Comment: Please try to add height:auto for html tag instead of height:100%.

Answer (score 0):

Make these changes in your Stylesheet

```
body{padding:0;margin:0;}

#container{margin: 0 auto;}
#header{margin: 0 0 40px;}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it did not work out. I applied your suggestion: http://web.fc.up.pt/DGSIII/bug_height/